# SSRS reports not visible to all users in spite of permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, windows-authentication

I have added a SSRS report to one of my department home pages and two things concern me:

1. It is very slow - almost a minute to render and any slicing takes a minute as well. 
   Reporting services installed on the sharepoint box and SQL db engine on a different box.    Reporting Server running in integrated mode and successfully paired with sharepoint.
2. I have added the report using the admin account. But in spite of adding new users to the  owners' group they are unable to view the report. What am I missing here? 
   I am using claims based with NTLM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions of the Report Library where the reports(.rdl) are uploaded.

At times,report library will need contribute level access rights for all the users who wish to see the reports inside this library. Also it is advised that **do not** use inherited permissions on the report library. Stop inheriting permissions and give permissions directly on the report library.

Additionally, if you are calling the report through a report viewer webpart inside a page , ensure the permission levels for the users are the same to that of the report library.

Thirdly, check all the datasource files, rdl files are checked in and published.

Let us know if this resolves your issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for the post Moss. I get the idea. However, what concerns me is that I would have to give contribute access to a user who I would like to treat as a visitor in order for him to see the reports and secondly, shouldn't the library inherit permissions if I were to assign a user to the site's owner group?